# Unable to overwrite bootstrap classes with css stylesheet in php project

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at some answers here and tried them but it still doesn't work. I have a bootstrap file and a style.css file in the head section.

Bootstrap file(lux.css) works fine but I have been trying to overwrite some bootstrap classes in my styles.css but it isn't working.

They both are in the same folder, which is css. Inline styling is possible in html elements though. This is the html head section:

```
<head>
        <title>IP</title>
        <meta name="description" content="IP">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon32.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lux.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" >         
</head>
```

This is the footer:

```
<footer class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="float-left ml-5">
                <p>
                    Copyright &copy <?php echo date('Y'); ?> IP. All Rights Reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/terms-of-service.html">Terms of Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">         
            function initialize() {
                <?php if(!$data_error){ ?>
                var latitude = <?php echo $data['geoplugin_latitude']; ?>;
                var longitude = <?php echo $data['geoplugin_longitude']; ?>;
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: <?php echo $zoom_level; ?>,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title:"IP Location!"
                });
                <?php } ?>
            }
        </script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=<?php echo $google_maps_api_key; ?>"></script>
    </body>

</html>

CSS
```

```
footer.row {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Are your overrides set to the same specificity or higher than the original styles?  Can you show an example of one of your overridden styles?

Comment: I might be missing something, which classes are you trying to override? I can't see any bootstrap styles in the provided code?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Can you please check ip.trafficvilla.com? Look at the footer. I want copyright to the left and the menu on the right. But the row is half way to the left. If I use width: 100% in chrome inspect then it works. But when I try the same thing in my stylesheet it doesn't work. For specificity I used footer.row as there are other row classes in the html element. I have also tried to style it in the bootstrap file with footer.row but doesn't work.

Comment: lux.css is the bootstrap theme file from bootswatch.com.

Comment: Provide relevant source code. You want help to override bootstrap classes but you haven't provided any markup using bootstrap classes. Unless you're using a preprocessor, it's difficult to override a bootstrap class, theres a few things to take into consideration, such as loading times of external resources. You're better off creating new classes that override styles of an element and attaching them to your elements that have the bootstrap classes.

Comment: updated with more code

Comment: what version of boostrap

Comment: I think it's bacause you've given navbar class to footer, and navbar class is flex. Try footer{display:block;} or footer.navbar{display:block;}

Comment: Pete, lux.css is the latest bootstrap. 
temirbek, should I use that inline or in the styles.css file?

Answer (score 0):

I added one classes `footer-cover` and style `p` tag

HTML

```
<footer class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
<div class="row footer-cover">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>
                    Copyright &copy <?php echo date('Y'); ?> IP. All Rights Reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/terms-of-service.html">Terms of Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer-cover {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 !important;;
}
.footer-cover p {
    margin-top: 10px !important;;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;;
}
```

Try to paste it at the end of your `lux.css`

Comment: Yuck!  Only use important to override inline styles that you have no control over otherwise yur css will become unmanagable

Comment: Nope it wont most of the WordPress styles sheet styles uses !important to override their styles and also i didn't see bootstrap styles in your head tag

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Can you please check ip.trafficvilla.com? Look at the footer. I want copyright to the left and the menu on the right. But the row is half way to the left. If I use width: 100% in chrome inspect then it works. But when I try the same thing in my stylesheet it doesn't work. For specificity I used footer.row as there are other row classes in the html element. I have also tried to style it in the bootstrap file with footer.row but doesn't work.

Comment: i'll looking into it and provide you a solution in a while

Comment: @Zak updated my answer have a look and do let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Just tried that in lux.css as well as styles.css. Doesn't work. The classes doesn't even appear in the inspect console.

Comment: Ok first inspect your css both files and open them in browser and find your css which you have written may be your editing the in the wrong directory (path issue may be)

Comment: sorry to ask you but how do i open my css files in browser? I inspected the element in dev tools console but footer-over isn't there. This is frustrating mate. I have spent hours on this since yesterday. May be it's not possible to overwrite in phn files?

Comment: open inspect element and click on head it show all you CSS and Script which you have in your project then click on style.css or lux.css it will open that file and then Ctrl+F to find your style OR right click on link an open in new window it will show your styles sheet in new tab

Comment: It is possible to overtire styles of php files use this code-pen to write your desire code like this https://codepen.io/AndreiRo/pen/pbPrYo